Django HTTPResponseRedirect not redirecting to the url but rather adding the integer to the url
This is my view.py file
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponseNotFound, Http404, HttpResponsePermanentRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.shortcuts import render

articles = {
    'sports': 'sports page',
    'finance' : 'finance page',
    'tech' : 'tech page',
}

def home_view(request):
    return HttpResponse("My App Home Page")

def news_view(request, topic):
    try:
        result = articles[topic]
        return HttpResponse(result)
    except:
        raise Http404("404 Generic view error")


def mul_view(request,num1,num2):
    num_result = num1 * num2
    result = f"{num1} * {num2} = {num_result}"
    return HttpResponse(str(result))

def num_page_view(request, num_page):
    topic_list = list(articles.keys())
    topic = topic_list[num_page]
    return HttpResponseRedirect(topic)

and this is my url file of the app
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:num_page>/', views.num_page_view, name='num_page'),
    # path('', views.home_view, name='home'),
    path('<topic>/', views.news_view, name='topic-page'),
    path('<int:num1>/<int:num2>/', views.mul_view, name='multiply'),  
]

What's happening here is a bit hard to explain for me as english is not my first language
but here is my best effort.
I have created a function num_page_view that takes a number as a parameter and has a list of all keys of articles dictionary then the number is provided to the list as an index and stored into a variable topic that is then send as the output in the HttpResponseRedirect
then i added a a new path that takes links to the num_page_view but instead of redirecting it to the topic it rather concatinates the integer to the url with the topic
For eg.
my_app/1/
should return my_app/finance but instead it concatinates that number to the url and makes it my_app/1/finance even though I am using HttpResponseRedirect which logically should return the given url name that I am providing it through the topic variable

That is because it redirects to finance, which is a relative path, so it will append finance/ to the URL.
You can use:
def num_page_view(request, num_page):
    topic_list = list(articles.keys())
    topic = topic_list[num_page]
    return HttpResponseRedirect(f'/my_app/{topic}')
but a more robust way is to use redirect(…) [Django-doc]:
from django.shortcuts import redirect


def num_page_view(request, num_page):
    topic_list = list(articles.keys())
    topic = topic_list[num_page]
    return redirect('topic-page', topic=topic)

Thank you for answering my question, your solution is working except for the finance page, whenever I am giving 1 as an input in num_page it returns my_app/1/finance so I added another movies in the dictionary at its place now finance is working as the input is 2. but movies is not working as it returns http://127.0.0.1:8000/my_app/1/finance even though I altered the dictionary :- articles = {
'sports': 'sports page',
'movies' : 'movies page',
'finance' : 'finance page',
'tech' : 'tech page',
}

So basically 1 as the input is not working otherwise everything works with ur solution, if u have any suggestions plz do tell.

Instead of relying on the index of the topic_list to fetch the topic, you can directly access the topic using the num_page as the key. This way, you avoid any confusion with URL patterns and directly construct the URL using the topic retrieved from the dictionary, so:
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def num_page_view(request, num_page):
    topic_list = list(articles.keys())
    if num_page < len(topic_list):
        topic = topic_list[num_page]
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('topic-page', kwargs={'topic': topic}))
    else:
        # Handle invalid page numbers
        return redirect('home')


Thank you for taking your time and answering my question, much appreciated.

@Krattza Happy to hear that the problem has been resolved ;)
